# Deploy expo app to GitHub Pages using Action

Tags: react-native, github, expo, github-pages

I am trying to build an Action on GitHub to have always up-to-date the web version of my app. However, it is not updating.

For the first deploy, I followed the [expo deploy to GitHub Pages documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/distribution/publishing-websites/#github-pages). Then, I built the following workflow:

```yaml
name: Web
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  web:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: ⚙️ Set up repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: ❇️ Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3.6.0
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name:  Set up Expo
        uses: expo/expo-github-action@v7
        with:
          expo-version: latest
          token: ${{ secrets.EXPO_TOKEN }}

      - name:  Install dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name: ⤴️ Export the app
        run: |
          git remote set-url origin https://git:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}.git
          yarn deploy -- -u "github-actions-bot <support+actions@github.com>"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            
      - name:  Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./
```

I also changed the Pages settings to deploy from an Action.
[image]

However, when the action ran it did not update the website. I decided to change back to the branch deployment, but now my site is crashing.
[image]

Have anyone ever done it? I could not find any reference browsing on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The following action works:

```yaml
name: Web
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
  
jobs:
  web:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: ⚙️ Set up repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: ❇️ Setup Node.js environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3.6.0
        with:
          node-version: 16.x

      - name:  Set up Expo
        uses: expo/expo-github-action@v7
        with:
          expo-version: latest
          token: ${{ secrets.EXPO_TOKEN }}

      - name:  Install dependencies
        run: yarn install

      - name:  Export the app
        run: |
          git remote set-url origin https://git:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}.git
          yarn deploy -- -u "github-actions-bot <support+actions@github.com>"
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```